# Storing rehydrated beans

Tags: storage-method, beans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can I store soaked beans before cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/how-long-can-i-store-soaked-beans-before-cooking)
>   [Can you preserve canned kidney beans so that they still have their shape?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/can-you-preserve-canned-kidney-beans-so-that-they-still-have-their-shape)

If I pre-soak/cook a large amount of dried beans in advance, what is the best way to store them for future use?

If freezing is an option, do I freeze them in the cooking water, or drain them and put them in an airtight container?