# Can I freeze soaked+boiled (but not fully cooked) kidney beans?

Tags: freezing, beans

I soaked too many beans for my chilli, and couldn't fit them all in my slow cooker.  The kidney beans were the last to go in due to their need for a hard boil, so they're what's left.

I won't have the chance to use them up in the next few days, so I intend to drain and freeze them.  I reckon I can assume they will be safe, so I'm interested in quality - things like:

- Will I need to do anything special to them when I defrost them?
- Are they likely to fall apart (still useful, but for different foods)?
- Will they soften?

[Storing rehydrated beans](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21481/20413) also mentions  freezing, but was closed as a duplicate of [How long can I store soaked beans before cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13340/20413), which doesn't address freezing at all.  So even if this question turns out to be a duplicate, it's not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I've actually already put them in the freezer, drained, but have asked the question as I first thought of it, because I think it's more generally useful that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it, and it worked.

Specifically having frozen the drained, boiled, but still hard beans for a few weeks I deforsted them in the fridge and added them to Dal Makhani, also made in the slow cooker.  By the time the black lentils were fully cooked, after several hours on high, the kidney beans were also soft, and split but not falling to bits.  So within the tolerance of slow cooking, there was no need to adjust anything.